# myRectangle.calculateArea(); returns error "package myRectangle does not exist"

Tags: java, netbeans, method-call

**Rectangle**

```
public class Rectangle {

  private double width;
  private double length; 


public Rectangle(double L, double W){
  length = L;
  width = W;
}

public void setLength(double Length){
  if (length>=0 && length <=20)
    length = Length;
else{
  length = 0;
}
}
public double getLength(){
  return length;
}
public void setWidth(double Width){
  if (width>=0 && length <=20)
    width = Width;
else{
    width = 0;
}
}
public double getWidth(){
  return width;
}

public void calculatePerimeter(){
  System.out.println("The perimeter of rectangle is: " + 2 * (length + width));
}
public void calculateArea(){
  System.out.println("The area of the rectangle is: " + (length * width));
}
}
```

**TestRectangle**

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class TestRectangle {
public static void main(String[] args){

Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
  Rectangle myRectangle = new Rectangle (0,0);//I did the same thing in a 
//previous assignment, and someone else who did this assignment (code found 
//online) also did this. It worked before but seems useless now?

System.out.println("Enter length: ");
  double L = input.nextDouble();
  System.out.println();

System.out.println("Enter width: ");
  double W = input.nextDouble();
  System.out.println();
}
myRectangle.calculateArea();//here
myRectangle.calculatePerimeter();//and here is where I get the error
//<identifier> expected, package myRectangle does not exist
}
```

I am trying to create a program "Rectangle" to calculate the area and perimeter of a rectangle, and then create a test program to run program "Rectangle"
I have copied code from a previous assignment called "Date", where the basic idea is similar, but when I get to the end of the program where I need to call on "calculateArea();" and "calculatePerimeter();" in the test program, I get an error telling me that package myRectangle doesn't exist.... can someone tell me why this is happening? A similar code worked in the previous assignment, and I found someone else's code for the same "Rectangle" program and it shows the same error. Did I do something wrong or is there something wrong with my NetBeans?

**This is the code I based the Rectangle and TestRectangle program off of**
**Date**

```
public class Date {
private int month;
private int day;
private int year;

public Date(int m, int d, int y){
    month = m;
    day = d;
    year = y;
}

public void setMonth(int Months){
    if(Months>=0 && Months <= 12)
        month=Months;
    else{
        month=0;
    }
}
public int getMonth(){
    return month;
}

public void setDay(int Days){
    if(Days>= 0 && Days<=31)
        day = Days;
        else{
                day=0;
                }
}

public int getDay(){
    return day;
}

public void setYear(int Years){
    year=Years;
}
public int getYear(){
    return year;
}
public void displayDate(){
    System.out.printf
            ("%d/%d/%d\n", getMonth(), getDay(), getYear() );
}
}
```

**TestDate**

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class DateTest {
public static void main(String[] args){
  Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

Date myDate = new Date(0,0,0);

System.out.println("Justine Dodge, assignment 6\n");


System.out.println("Please enter month: ");
  int m = input.nextInt();
  myDate.setMonth(m);
  System.out.println();


System.out.println("Enter day: ");
  int d = input.nextInt();
  myDate.setDay(d);//assign d to Day?
  System.out.println();//output blank line

System.out.println("Enter year: ");
  int y = input.nextInt();
  myDate.setYear(y);
  System.out.println();


myDate.displayDate();
```

}
}

Comment: What is package name of Rectangle class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in the TestRectangle you are closing the main method before calling these functions

```
} // this should be at at the end of the main function 
myRectangle.calculateArea();//here
myRectangle.calculatePerimeter();//and here is where I get the error
```

i.e

```
myRectangle.calculateArea();//here
myRectangle.calculatePerimeter();//and here is where I get the error
}
```

This will remove the compilation error. Now when you run it , you will get both area and perimeter as 0 because in the constructor , you are passing values of length and width as 0  and not really using the length and width taken as input.
To resolve this issue, insstead of passing 0,0 in constructor,
try to pass L,W in constructor like this

```
  Rectangle myRectangle = new Rectangle (L,W);
myRectangle.getLength()); //
myRectangle.calculateArea();//here
myRectangle.calculatePerimeter();
```

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class TestRectangle {
public static void main(String[] args){

Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
//  Rectangle myRectangle = new Rectangle (0,0);//I did the same thing in a 
//previous assignment, and someone else who did this assignment (code found 
//online) also did this. It worked before but seems useless now?

System.out.println("Enter length: ");
  double L = input.nextDouble();
  System.out.println();

System.out.println("Enter width: ");
  double W = input.nextDouble();
  System.out.println();

  
  Rectangle myRectangle = new Rectangle (L,W);
//  System.out.println("get length " + myRectangle.getLength());
myRectangle.calculateArea();//here
myRectangle.calculatePerimeter();//and here is where I get the error
//<identifier> expected, package myRectangle does not exist
}
}
```

then you will get o/p like this
[image]

Comment: So I changed the constructors to L and W, but it tells me that it "cannot find variable L or W" in the error notification

Comment: you might be trying to replace it in the first line where you had mentioned , instead you have to use it after defining L and W. I've added the complete working code in the answer.

Comment: did it work ? or some other issue is popping up ?

Comment: Hi! So sorry, I don't have wifi at home and I didn't get the notification :O I just changed it and it works now, thanks so much!

Comment: I am curious though: how come the format had to be different than the "Date" program? I am new to Java not very technologically savvy, but I assumed it would require the same basic format but instead it was a little different.... unless I just read it wrong lol

Comment: in the Date program , there is a line which is calling the setter Method which updates the values. you've that missing in the rectangle class :)

Comment: Done! Thanks for your help :D